# unable to redirect to html page

Tags: php, html

my problem is after i successfully log in,it is not redirect to page that i supposed to go.

plus, i'm using apache server.

below is the PHP part i think need to be fix.

```
if($count==1){
    // Register $Username, $Password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("Username");
    session_register("Password");
    echo "Correct Username & Password";

    header("location:$http://localhost/.../contacts.html");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    header("location:../php/error.php");
    }
```

by using

`header("location:$http://localhost/.../contacts.html");`

i get 403 Forbidden error..
this error were not appear on web page but on firebug.

if i replace with

`header( 'Location: http://localhost/.../contacts.html' ) ;`

or

`header("Location: ./../contacts.html");`

or

`header('Location: ./../contacts.html');`

it gives me no error but its only respond in firebug by showing the html code of the contacts.html and not showing the page itself..

please help me with explanation and how to solve this problem

and sorry for any grammar mistakes and difficulty to understand this :)

Comment: Though we are pretty sure of what error you're getting, please always let us know the actual error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you can't use `header` if you print some html before.
(You can't even put a blank space before).

Just remove the `echo` and it should be fine.

Comment: No reason. I've sent it a bit fast, and I can't undo. Or maybe I can ? Edit: I can't.

Comment: You could try flagging your own answer and ask a mod to undo it. Not sure how ethical that would be tho.

Comment: Not ethical for sure, and not possible. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69017/undo-community-wiki

Comment: i just move the "echo"..what I've understand, header function cant be with echo right?hehe..but i still dont get to direct go to contacts.html  page...when i check in firebug, its only show the html code of contacts.html in the response section..why it not appear to be the contacts.html page beside the code in firebug? :p

Comment: @muxisar a moderator can undo a comm wiki.

Comment: @Shredder, yeah, but I accept my mistake and the shame coming with. @Doherty make sure that you don't have any `echo` left before this function, use this form to redirect: `header('Location: http://[path]/contacts.html');` and tell me, if the page is not printed but loaded on firebug, what's printed on the screen ? The same page as before ? You get some php error ?

Comment: i have used the suggestion code..yes @muxisar..the result same page as before..i dont think php error..but i get syntax error said."(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HT...p://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> "... :p i think its just a silly error i've made..:p

Answer (score 1):

Once you `echo` anything or send any output, your headers get sent. Therefore, you cannot manipulate your headers after doing so. You'll find lots of posts about this problem by a simple search of your error message on SO

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent

What is the point of echoing something anyway when you redirect them on the next line? :p

**Edit:** Is there a reason for the dollar sign in this statement: `header("location:$http://localhost/.../contacts.html");`? Is `$http` a variable? Maybe try removing the dollar sign..

Comment: $ sign is not a variable..i just try using that suggestion code that i get from other site..but no luck :p

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `$` sign before http and it's done...